# jquery flip multiple images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function where I can call it to flip multiple images one after another. Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
function flipImage(totCount, flipCount) {

    totCount--;
    var cnt = flipCount;
    cnt++;
    var id = '#flip'+cnt;

    $(id).flip({
        speed:400,
        color: 'red',
        direction: 'rl',
        onAnimation: if (cnt > 0){flipImage(totCount, cnt)},
        onEnd: function () {

            $(id).show(400);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is not working in code.?

Comment: It says syntax error at onAnimation: if (cnt > 0){flipImage(totCount, cnt)},

Comment: yes thats correct...it will give you error..

Comment: W/out looking at a jsfiddle, i'd guess that your code is flipping all the images at once. Look into delaying the flip of each image by `cnt * someAmountOfTime` through your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `conditions` like that instead use.

```
onAnimation: function(){ 
   if (cnt > 0){flipImage(totCount, cnt)}
},
```